# Scraping TrusPilot with Laravel before rendering a view

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently using Goutte to scrape Trustpilot using the function below.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        //the link to your TrustPilot review website here
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/randomsite.com');
        $webPage = ($crawler->html());
        $json = Str::between($webPage,'<script type="application/ld+json" data-business-unit-json-ld>', ']}]
        </script>');
        $reviewsJson = ((preg_replace("/\s\s+/", "", $json).']}]'));
        $reviews = json_decode($reviewsJson); //object to be passed to view for rendering reviews
     
    }
```

It basically scrapes for the reviews and then I intend to loop the reviews my homepage to display the each review.

What I want to know is the effect of this speed-wise, am I better off occasionally scraping storing to my database or will the application be fine with the scraping each time the homepage is loaded?

The app is running on Elastic Beanstalk on AWS

Any ideas? What methods can I use to test and evaluate the performance of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the cache to avoid **scraping** the data every time the index method is called.

```php
public function index()
{
    // __Scrape__ once and then every subsequent call to index will use the cached value until it expires in 1 week.
    $reviews = Cache::remember('reviews', now()->addDays(7), function () {
        $client = new Client();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/randomsite.com');
        $webPage = ($crawler->html());
        $json = Str::between($webPage,'<script type="application/ld+json" data-business-unit-json-ld>', ']}]
        </script>');
        $reviewsJson = ((preg_replace("/\s\s+/", "", $json).']}]'));

        return json_decode($reviewsJson);
    });
}
```

- [Cache - Retrieve & Store](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#retrieve-store)

Comment: I was literally thinking of doing this on my drive home earlier. Thanks very much!